# Android: Right place to create notification channel

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

*I know how to create notification and notification channel in an Android app.*

I showed many examples that say create notification channel while you generate a notification from FCM listener. So when the app receives notification at that point it generates channel.

But I saw in many apps, it create all channels without receiving any notification.

Question: **From where we should create a notification channel?**

Comment: Inside onMessageReceived in your FirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: I personally create mine during my application's `onCreate()`. In the [Google Notifications sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Notifications) they create it in the MainActivity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to create Notification Channels from Android O Api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46294833/4625829)

Comment: @AL. If you notice in the [Google notification sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Notifications/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/wearnotifications/MainActivity.java), It will create a channel while generating a notification.

Comment: Which is created in the MainActivity. This is all up to your preferences. In the possible duplicate post, creating the notification channel before posting the notification is also fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to create Notification Channels from Android O Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46294833/correct-way-to-create-notification-channels-from-android-o-api)

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels):

> Creating an existing notification channel with its original values
>   performs no operation, so it's safe to call this code when starting an
>   app.